# WCF callback + WF4

Tags: wcf, callback, workflow-foundation-4

How to call duplex wcf callback service in WF4. Please give a simple example

Answer (score 2):

WF4 has no direct for normal duplex WCF services. Because of the often long running nature it uses something called durable duplex services which is basically the original caller also being a full WCF service. See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/05/03/workflow-4-services-and-duplex-communications.aspx) for a blog post on how to set this up.

If you want to support regular WCF duplex services you would need to create a custom activity and implement it using regular C#/VB code.